# Using braces with equations - how to make fractional terms 'bigger'

Tags: spacing, equations, braces, fractions

I have some equations which display perfectly until I put them inside a brace and they become 'squashed'. Example:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
    u =  \frac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial x},
    v =  \frac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial y}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}     
    u =  \frac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial x}\\
    v =  \frac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial y}
\end{array}\right.
\end{alignat}
```

i.e. the tilde notation cannot be seen clearly in the second equation inside the brace. I have some complex equations which look brutal inside braces is there a way to display these more clearly?

Comment: You use `\begin{alignat}{2}`, but do not align whatever!

Comment: Material in an `array` environment is set in `\textstyle` math mode by default, even if the`array` is embedded in a display math environment. Hence, either use `\dfrac` inside the `array` to get "large" fractional expressions, or use another math environment that sets its material in `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using a `dcases` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package) instead of an `array` environment for the second equation. Incidentally, since no vertical aligning seems to be performed, consider using basic `equation` environments instead of `alignat` environments. In addition, you may want to use `\widetilde` instead of `\tilde` for the capital `X` letters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'dcases' environment
\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
    u =  \frac{\partial\widetilde{X}}{\partial x}, \quad
    v =  \frac{\partial\widetilde{X}}{\partial y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}     
    u =  \frac{\partial\widetilde{X}}{\partial x}\\[1ex]
    v =  \frac{\partial\widetilde{X}}{\partial y}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\dfrac` from `amsmath` and some vertical correction should be enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{alignat}{2}
    u =  \frac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial x},v =  \frac{\partial    \tilde{X}}{\partial y}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}     
    u =  \dfrac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial x}\\[9pt] %the value up to you
    v =  \dfrac{\partial\tilde{X}}{\partial y}
\end{array}\right.
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]